# Limit groups are CSA

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I am trying to understand the below proof better:

[image]

Comment: What is the source of this proof?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604137.pdf
Lemma 1.11

Comment: The author (Henry WIlton) is quite active on MathOverflow, so you might want to ask the question there...

Comment: I will post there as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say I don't understand your question 1. Surely you know what "injective" means?

Actually, I think there may be a small typo in the proof, which is perhaps what is causing your confusion for question 2.  The hypothesis $h\in gHg^{-1}\cap H$ means that $h\in H$ and $g^{-1}hg\in H$ (not $ghg^{-1}$, as written). Therefore, since $H$ is abelian, $h$ and $g^{-1}hg$ commute, ie $[h,g^{-1}hg]=1$.

So far, this is all completely elementary.  Question 3 just needs a very basic fact about free groups, namely that the centralizer of any non-trivial element is cyclic. The identity $f([h,g^{-1}hg])=1$ implies that $f(h)$ and $f(g^{-1}hg)$ commute, so both live in the centralizer of $f(h)$, which is a cyclic subgroup.